# Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using JavaScript or jquery possible means please write an some example codes?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to save HTML page as PDF using jquery possible means please write an some example codes?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this on client side. It is not possible to save a file locally without involving the local client as it is a security problem to client machine.